# Trigger an email from Google Sheet when a condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a program in Apps Script & The purpose is to send an email alert for multiple recipients from Google Sheet when a condition is met. The email body should contain an HTML table.

The Google Sheet has data in 3 columns (A, B & C). Email should trigger when the following condition is met: **Column C > 10**

As per the below program, I am getting the alert in table format, But I am unable to add this condition to trigger an email. Recipients should not receive the email if the above condition is not met.

```
function sendMail(){
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Status")
 var data = sh.getRange("A1:C20").getValues();
  //var htmltable =[];

var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="2" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:3px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:Black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:grid;font-style:Times;'
var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

htmltable += '<tr>';

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

     htmltable += '</tr>';
}

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);

      var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("A1:A20");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'Order Status Update','' ,{htmlBody: htmltable});
}
```

Link to a sample Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpA3kTJFnUFRJ4CTNeSwJNEfSGAezchEuwfMi6ZGQoc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. About `Email should trigger when the following condition is met: Column C > 10`, in your expected result, do you want to send an email including all rows when at least, the value of column "C" is more than 10? Or, do you want to send an email including all rows that the value of column "C" is more than 10?

Comment: Email should be send excluding the row which has the column "C" value < 10  or  Email including all rows that the value of column "C" is more than 10

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send an email including all rows that the value of column "C" is more than 10.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = sh.getRange("A1:C20").getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var data = sh.getRange("A1:C20").getValues().filter((r, i) => i == 0 || (i > 0 && r[2] > 10));
if (data.length == 1) return;
```

- By this modification, an email including all rows that the value of column "C" is more than 10 is sent. And, when there are no rows where the value of column "C" is more than 10, no email is sent.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank You. It's working perfectly 
But just a small clarification, I need the column headings as well. Would it possible to add the column headings ?

Comment: @Pramod Thank you for replying. About `But just a small clarification, I need the column headings as well. Would it possible to add the column headings ?`, I modified the above script. Please confirm it. In this modification, when the data is only the header row, the email is not sent.

Comment: @Pramod About `Thanks Tanaike. It worked `, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I could not find the accept button